# unable to recognize ole stream error while running it using Jenkins

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jenkins-plugins

I am getting *unable to recognize ole stream error* while trying to run my selenium script from Jenkin however it is working fine while running it from local in eclipse.I am trying to connect to Excel sheet in this script using JXL

Excel is already saved in 97-2003 format(i know i am using JXL which does not support XLSX)  and working fine in local machine using eclipse but error is coming while running it from Jenkins. I have checked Slave and found that Office 2016 is installed in Slave machine and as well in my local machine

I should be able to connect to xls file without any issue as its working fine from my local machine. Please suggest

Code used to connect Excel:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;
static Sheet wrksheet;
    static Workbook wrkbook =null;
    static Hashtable dict= new Hashtable();
    private static int iDataSheetRow;

    //Create a Constructor
    public static void init(String ExcelSheetPath) throws BiffException, IOException
    {
        //Initialize
        wrkbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(ExcelSheetPath));
        wrksheet = wrkbook.getSheet(0);
        //setiDataSheetRow(0);
    }
```

Error log:

```
jxl.read.biff.BiffException: Unable to recognize OLE stream
  at jxl.read.biff.CompoundFile.<init>(CompoundFile.java:116)
  at jxl.read.biff.File.<init>(File.java:127)
  at jxl.Workbook.getWorkbook(Workbook.java:221)
  at jxl.Workbook.getWorkbook(Workbook.java:198)
  at utilities.ExcelSheetDriver.init(ExcelSheetDriver.java:21)
  at smokeTestRun.TC_BarclaysYS.beforeMethod(TC_BarclaysYS.java:26)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124
```

Comment: Hello. Just saying something is not working is not going to help the community in debugging the issue. Please provide the error stack trace (if any) and what code have you written which is failing?

Comment: @demouser123 Thanks for response.. I have updated the details above. please help. let me know if any other information required.